# some trouble with the re-module (specifically: .(DOT) in character class)

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string

```
str = "some_var = \n {'LOL'}"
```

and I want to run a `re`-search on it...

```
re.search(r'some_var =([.\s]+)\}', str)
```

To my knowledge, I should be searching any character (including newline characters) until hitting a `}` in the string and grouping everything between the `=` and it.

Why am I getting `None` as the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.` doesn't match any character including newline -- in fact it matches any character *except* newline. See:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

You have to use `DOTALL` mode.

I'm not sure what your intention is with `[.\s]`. It looks like "any character plus whitespace". But whitespace is a character, so you can just say "any character". I think this probably suffices:

```
re.search(r'some_var =(.+)\}', str, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

P.S. `str` is a built-in. Don't call variables `str`.

Comment: Sorry for accepting this so late.— BTW, back in the day, I was only I need of the CONTENTS between the {brackets} (it was JSON data) — I remember the people answering here on my question helping me a LOT and my confusion/problems were immediately solved. — The help was/is greatly appreciated, to this day!

Comment: @TheGeekGuy note that using `.*` will match until the last occurrence of a `}` and will not stop at the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a character class the dot matches a literal dot so your regex would match one or more times a dot or a whitespace character `([.\s]+)` in a capturing group.

You could match not a `}` using a negated character class:

`some_var =([^}]+)}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CCqpAv/2)

**Explanation**

- `some_var =` Match literally
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[^}]+` Match not a `}` one or more times using a negated character class (including newlines)
- `)` Close capturing group
- `}` Match `}`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IGMBG2658)

Comment: I don't think your pattern will match their example. Can you include some working code?

Comment: @Denziloe I have added a demo.

Comment: Thanks. They didn't state output but I think the question would like everything after = in their grouping, including any newlines.

Comment: @Denziloe Then negated character class also matches line break characters. The OP mentioned  "until hitting a } in the string and grouping everything between the = and it.". I am reading this as the content after the equals sign and before the closing curly.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It really helped understand the issue with my method (aka: dot in character brackets)... and presented the better / obvious solution...